# Are encrypted fields not masked in Visualforce however the "View Encrypted Data" permission is set?

Tags: visualforce, encryption, platform-encryption

In an org where Contact.Name is encrypted via [Salesforce Shield Platform Encryption](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/security_pe_overview.htm) and for an SA user (where the SA profile has "View Encrypted Data" unchecked) normal list views and detail pages mask the name by displaying ****** ************ instead of the name as expected.

However, this Visualforce displays the name not masked:

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact">
    <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.Name}"/>
</apex:page>
```

Reviewing the documentation I can see no mention of Visualforce support, thought there is this "Custom Lightning Components" comment:

> When viewed in a custom Lightning
>   component, encrypted data is not masked, even if the user doesn't have
>   the "View Encrypted Data" permission.

So can anyone confirm that encrypted fields are not masked in Visualforce? Are we meant to write our own masking logic?

**PS**

The page is using API 37 and I get the same problem with a non-SA profile i.e. the unmasked name is presented when "View Encrypted Data" is unchecked. The org is eu11 which doesn't move to Winter '17 until Saturday. I don't see this specific problem posted in [Known Issues](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_index?keywords=platform%20encryption).

Comment: i assume the VF page is at least Summer 15?

Comment: @cropredy Yeah was a page create via the web Setup UI so current API version.

Comment: I just tried this and it worked just fine for me(value masked in VF as well). So i can surly tell you that its not VF issue.

Comment: Just FYI there was bug in older version. you may want to double check the API version is 37.

Comment: @AtulRajguru9 Did just double check the version and it is 37. Perhaps it is something to do with the profile - as I mentioned in the question I just tested as SA? Any other thoughts on what I might be missing? But great to know that it does work.

Comment: @AtulRajguru9 Apologies for the second massage, but is the org you tested in a Winter '17 one?

Comment: Sorry for delay, got busy with production issue. The org is Dev org and it on Summer 16.

Comment: @AtulRajguru9 No problem. I've created a case on this with Salesforce support - looks like a bug where Contact.Name is not masked whereas Contact.FirstName and Contact.LastName are...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There does appear to be an issue with the `Name` field in particular --- if you use `First Name` or `Last Name` individually, however, the data IS returned encrypted. I'd report this as a bug -- but at least you can workaround it by composing `Name` from its component fields.

Here's the VF page I used for testing:

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact">
    Name: <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.Name}"/><br/>
    First Name: <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.FirstName}"/><br/>    
    Last Name: <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.LastName}"/><br/>        
</apex:page>
```

Which returned these results:

[image: Encrypted Contact data]

Comment: Thanks - taking your page I see exactly the same thing. Have opened a case. A colleague had a masked field appearing unmasked in a report too; looks like there are some holes in this at the moment.